# How to setup TeamCity automatic labeling against JIRA that requires issue reference on commit?

Tags: svn, teamcity, jira

We use TeamCity for our automated builds and JIRA (Atlassian OnDemand) for issue tracking.  Our Subversion repository is also hosted by Atlassian as part of our OnDemand service, and we have enabled a pre-commit hook to require an issue for each check-in.  I would like to setup our TeamCity instance to automatically label the project repository after each successful build.  The pre-commit hook is preventing the label commit though.  Is there any way to specify in TeamCity an issue to be included with the commit to label the build?

I would prefer to keep the pre-commit hook active so that we enforce relating code changes to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to specify the SVN commit message that TeamCity uses when labeling.
That can be configured in the VCS root, **Labeling message** setting.

However, instead of providing a - presumably generic - issue ID just to satisfy the pre-commit hook, I'd suggest updating the pre-commit script to not enforce the issue ID requirement when the commit is made by TeamCity, but leave it in place for other commits.  For example, you could check the commit username using **svnlook author**.

Comment: Thanks! At first I thought this was not working. After adding an issue number to the labeling message it still failed. This was due to commits on externals in the repository failing.  After adding issue IDs for the externals as well, it worked. I agree that modifying the pre-commit script would be best, but this is not currently possible with the Atlassian OnDemand hosted solution.